# Have grub signal hiberfil.sys present

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 16.04, windows, hibernate

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS will not start on a dual-boot machine if Windows *hiberfil.sys* is present. This is a *good* thing, since it helps prevent lost of open work, but occasionally I forget and select *Ubuntu* from grub, forcing me to shut down and then reboot.

It would be helpful if there were an extension to grub to warn of this issue, possibly as shown below:

> Ubuntu        <= not available
>
> Windows    <= hibernated

Is it feasible to add such an extension to grub? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you mounting your Windows partition in Ubuntu? Have you modified your /etc/fstab file to do so? You need to turn off FAST BOOT and HIBERNATION in Windows, if you're going to be mounting the Windows partition in Ubuntu.

Comment: The Windows NTFS partition auto mounts in Ubunu, and I'd like to keep some files there (e.g. Calibre library) that are accessed by both Windows and Ubuntu. Actually, Ubuntu 16.04 LTS boots perfectly well with Fast Boot enabled; it is the hiberfil.sys that is the issue. I turn Hibernation *on* after booting to Windows, and *off* with **powercfg -h off** when booting Ubuntu, but forget occasionally. The question asks for help in having grub alert me when I forget.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I understand why you're mounting an NTFS partition in Ubuntu for sharing files. I do the same thing.

The problem is that FAST BOOT and HIBERNATION are incompatible with our dual-boot setup in so far as Windows filesystem is left in an inconsistent state.

Ubuntu notices when it tries to mount the partition so it stops the boot. Any changes that could be made to the NTFS filesystem from Ubuntu would probably be lost when rebooting Windows, as it'll want to restore the last known condition of the filesystem from the hiberfil.sys.

Running ntfsfix from Ubuntu will probably fix the hiberfil.sys problem, but at the risk of losing files, or corrupting, the Windows side.

I'm not aware of any script or extension to prewarn you at Ubuntu boot time that the hiberfil.sys exists and fix the problem for you.

It's just best to disable FAST BOOT and HIBERNATION in Windows.

Comment: Fast Boot does not cause an issue with Ubuntu 16.04, if not actually used (Windows "hybrid" shutdown), but it would be nice to have an alert if hybrid shutdown was last used, as well. It does not need to be disabled in UEFI though. However, if Hibernation is enabled, though not used, hiberfil.sys is still present.  So it appears you're stating there *is no answer* to this question?

Comment: The FAST BOOT setting that I'm discussing is not any UEFI "fast start" option, but a setting available under Power Settings control panel. You could mount the NTFS partitions read only, but of couse... And no, other than disabling FAST BOOT/HIBERNATION, then I'm personally not aware of the answer that you're looking for. Maybe somebody else can chime in. Cheers, Al